# Unable to launch Firefox browser from Selenium Webdriver version 3.4.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am facing an issue wherein I am unable to launch firefox from Selenium Webdriver version 3.4.0 from my Windows operating system (Windows 7) which is 64 bit.
Currently, firefox version 52.0.2 is installed on my machine.
I have also added selenium jar files to the library, still it is showing error.

**My code:**

```
package sanity;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Login
{
        public static void main(String[] args)    
        {
            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();    
            driver.close(); 
        }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:738)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$100(GeckoDriverService.java:41)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:330)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.toExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:108)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:104)
    at sanity.Login.main(Login.java:18)
```

After this, I downloaded GeckoDriverService form SeleniumHQ.org and ran below code, now after running below updated code with the Geckodriver path, firefox browser is getting launched but not closing automatically. Also I am getting some message in console.

**Code:**

```
package sanity;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Login 
{

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {

          String Firefoxdriverpath="C://Users//Ashish//Downloads//geckodriver-v0.16.0-win64//geckodriver.exe";

            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Firefoxdriverpath);

            WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.close(); 
        }

}
```

**Console:**

```
    1492944489305   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:12059
1492944489973   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser \\?\C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1492944491445   addons.manager  ERROR   startup failed: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE) [nsIFile.create]"  nsresult: "0x80070057 (NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm :: FileUtils_getDir :: line 70"  data: no] Stack trace: FileUtils_getDir()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:70 < FileUtils_getFile()@resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm:42 < AddonManagerInternal.validateBlocklist()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:700 < AddonManagerInternal.startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:870 < this.AddonManagerPrivate.startup()@resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm:3033 < amManager.prototype.observe()@resource://gre/components/addonManager.js:65
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 1677: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
1492944492505   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 50231
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 2585: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: AddonManager is not initialized
Apr 23, 2017 4:18:14 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
```

Kindly help.

Thanks,
Ashish Jain

Comment: Which version of gecko driver are you using?

Comment: Gecko driver version geckodriver-v0.16.0-win64

Comment: Check out my answer & update me the status. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try it again using "driver.quit" instead of "driver.close".

About the "Javascript error (AddonManager)" I'm still trying to figure out how to fix it too, if someone know a way please share with us :)

Comment: Just going thru [link] (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), there are few points in the changed section. Not sure if can help anything:                                                                
1) SendKeysParameters, which is used for the Element Send Keys and Send Alert Text commands, has been updated to take a string text field.
2) Disable Flash and the plugin container in Firefox by default, which should help mitigate the “Plugin Container for Firefox has stopped wroking” problems many users were reporting when deleting a session

Comment: with driver.quit, w/o login it is quitting the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the below code,

```
String Firefoxdriverpath="C://Users//Ashish//Downloads//geckodriver-v0.16.0-win64//geckodriver.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Firefoxdriverpath);
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);  
driver.close();
```

Please let me know if this is working.

Comment: Still getting same error and firefox is also not closing

Comment: @AshishJain - Please check the tests by downloading the old versions of the geckodriver. It may be due to the compatibility between the mozilla and geckodriver. Also try changing the location where the geckodriver has been kept. It is working fine in my machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue but finally got it solved by this small code below changed for selenium 3.4 capability-

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();

capabilities.setCapability("marionette", false); // true gives that Javascript error (AddonManager is not initialized)
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your Firefox version??

sometimes the problem is the incompatibility between the installed FireFox version and the geckodriver version

Answer (score 0):

About the "Javascript error (AddonManager)"... I almost went nuts today trying to fix this, since all the components were installed gradually within the last week.In the end I solved it.
Here's the solution and the explanation:
geckodriver v.0.16.0 "is only compatible with Selenium 3.4 and greater" (as it says on their page).
A week ago selenium 3.3.1 was the last version. As of April 21, selenium3.4.0 was released.
I had to recreate the project from scratch, re-adding the Selenium jars. For some reason simply replacing them on the old project, didn't do the trick.

Comment: I deleted old project, recreated new one and added jar files, still showing this error

Comment: Hi, I run into it again this morning, while configuring an enterprise computer. Here it worked by switching to geckodrive v.0.15.0  from [link] (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)  .Let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any significant error in your code as such. But you need to follow certain guidelines as follows:

While declaring `String Firefoxdriverpath` either you need to use single front slashes i.e "/"

e.g. `String Firefoxdriverpath="C:/Utility/BrowserDrivers/geckodriver.exe";`

OR you need to escape the back slashes i.e "\\"

e.g. `String Firefoxdriverpath="C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe";`

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: No it is still same

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. 
What helps is usage of `driver.quit();` instead of `driver.close();`

Answer (score 0):

Got this error when using Firefox version: 45.9.0; Selenium 3.4.0 and Gecko driver: 16.1.

Solution: Downgrade to gecko 16.0 and use:
System.setProperty("**webdriver.firefox.marionette**", "Path");

Hope this helps.